# Unittesting BizTalk map that read value from SSO

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2

I have a BizTalk 2013 R2 (x64) installed.
I have created a BTS map which read some user credential from SSO.
I created a unittest for testing this map but getting this error:

> An exeception of type 'Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.BizTalkTestAssertFailException' occurred in Microsoft.BizTalk.TestTools.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: Transformation Failure.

It seems like that my map doesn't have access to read from the SSO. I'm running the test from VS2013, so the user will be me. How can I change or run the test with different user?

I tried to create a Test.Setting file even this didn't help.

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as administrator and/or making sure the user it's running as has access to SSO

Answer (score 0):

Your user must belong to the "SSO Administrators" or "SSO Affiliate Administrators" (or equivalent if the groups were customized during the installation) group on the BizTalk Server.